# Ubuntu (GNOME) 14.04 just updated, and now cannot login to X server

Tags: nvidia, kernel, updates, xorg

I have just updated my Ubuntu gnome 14.04 and restarted the computer,
Now the system does not load the X and gnome. It is stuck in a black screen, and I can see some text flashes from time to time.

when I try to change terminal I have only a few seconds to login as root and kill gdm manually, or else it will change to the X terminal again.

Then, I try to login as a user and run startx manually,
it puts out the following error (taken from `/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log`):

```
[    99.897] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[    99.897] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    99.897] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    99.897] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    99.897] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    99.897]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.1.0
[    99.897]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    99.897] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    99.897] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    99.897] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    99.897] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    99.897]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    99.897]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    99.897] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    99.898] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    99.898] (EE) 
[    99.898] (EE) Backtrace:
[    99.898] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x560b13600fc8]
[    99.898] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x560b13460000+0x1a4ff9 [0x560b13604ff9]
[    99.898] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f0b955df000+0x36cb0) [0x7f0b95615cb0]
[    99.898] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpciaccess.so.0 (pci_io_read8+0x3) [0x7f0b9699f523]
[    99.898] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so (0x7f0b8f883000+0x56fc) [0x7f0b8f8886fc]
[    99.898] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so (0x7f0b8f883000+0xac61) [0x7f0b8f88dc61]
[    99.898] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so (0x7f0b8f883000+0xe7e0) [0x7f0b8f8917e0]
[    99.898] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so (xf86ExecX86int10+0x45) [0x7f0b8f889a15]
[    99.898] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so (VBEExtendedInit+0x84) [0x7f0b8faa8614]
[    99.898] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so (0x7f0b8fcae000+0x2f2a) [0x7f0b8fcb0f2a]
[    99.898] (EE) 10: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0xa7f) [0x560b134f59bf]
[    99.898] (EE) 11: /usr/bin/X (0x560b13460000+0x57dab) [0x560b134b7dab]
[    99.898] (EE) 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f0b95600f45]
[    99.898] (EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x560b13460000+0x4352e) [0x560b134a352e]
[    99.898] (EE) 
[    99.898] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x8
[    99.898] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    99.898] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    99.898] (EE) 
[    99.898] (EE)

-- End of quote
```

As far as I remember the last update was mostly for the kernel, and now it was updated from Linux 3.19.0-64-generic to 3.19.0-65-generic.
Now in the boot loader when I choose the last kernel Before this update, everything works well. only with the latest kernel it doesn't.

How can I fix this? 
Or how can I undo the latest update?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

disabling UEFI Secure Boot seems to solve that, it was probably had to do with 3rd party graphic drivers not loading while secure boot was on.

I used the update-secureboot-policy command and followed the instructions to disable it.